# Horizontally rotate the Viewport in 180 degrees to see the back side?

Tags: 3d-view, axis

Is there an easy way to rotate the view horizontally to see the backside, as from the first picture to the second picture?

I was following a phone modelling tutorial, and the guy jumped form the front side of the phone to the back side of the phone, but I couldn't find a way to do that. I have tried clicking combinations of the "X", "Y", "Z" circles on the top-right, but none of them resulted in the backside as the second picture. I can manually rotated the view using the middle mouse drag to end up as the second picture, but the axes are not perfectly aligned with the screen as the first picture, which was achieved by simply clicking the "Z" circle.

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you click on one of the letters X Y Z on the navigation cross it alight the view to be perpendicular to the selected axis and in ortographical, when you click again the same letter should make 180 turn to see exactly that view but from the back of the same axis

Comment: @Fowl Clicking the "Z" again rotates but rotates 180 vertically, not horizontally, thus the triangle becomes upside-down.

Comment: I think that your whole problem is because you are modeling in different axis than your tutorial guy. Click and click again alway makes it back view same results as the @thibsert wrote.

Comment: @Fowl is right. You're modeling in top view. Model in front view and switching front/back works as you want it. I use it myself all the time.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> is the shortcut for top view, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> is the shortcut for bottom view.

Same for <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> (front/back), <kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd> (right/left)

Comment: Pressing Ctrl + Num7 has the same effect as pressing the blue "Z" again; it shows the backside, but it rotates vertically so that the model is upside-down.